# Use ServiceNow forms for outbound post calls

Tags: rest, servicenow, outbound

I am trying to use the servicenow form field to populate the values of an external application with a create api call.

My attempt was to create a servicenow application with studio. In studio, I clicked "*Create Application File*" > "*OutBound Integrations*" > "*Rest Message*", and I was able to add the api endpoint, and I ran the test to make a post call to the api. And when I went to the api application, the value was there; so that's great! Now I'm trying to add a form to the servicenow application, so that the values added to the fields will not only show in servicenow, but also to the api. Is this possible, and how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to this was Business rule. In ServiceNow Studio, I created a new application and added Business Rule. In there, I was able to add a server-side script to make it work.

Here's a documentation from ServiceNow to make it work: 
https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/training/article/app_store_learnv2_rest_london_outbound_rest_integrations/app_store_learnv2_rest_london_exercise_write_a_script_to_invoke_the_rest_message?v=london